# Component style changes when placed inside widget in QT designer

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am developing an user interface using PyQt5 and QT designer. I have created a widget, placed some components inside it and distributed them as a form.

The problem is, every time a place a component inside the widget, its style changes. For example, in the caption below, the red rectangle shows a combobox inside the widget and the green one shows the same combobox outside it.

[image]

I would like to keep the combobox inside the widget but using the style of the one in the green rectangle.

Edit:

The following code creates the image below it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>260</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>60</width>
       <height>16</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Gender</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>80</x>
       <y>10</y>
       <width>104</width>
       <height>26</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>340</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>104</width>
      <height>26</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Gender</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: I added and edit with the code corresponding to a simple widget with a combobox inside and another combobox outside @eyllanesc so you can check both styles are different

Comment: In Linux I did not observe the problem, are you sure that only that code generates that behavior? if it's just that code then it's probably a bug.

Comment: I did not create the components in the picture programmatically, I just placed them using QT Designer and that piece of code was generated. Maybe is just a bug in Mac OS, maybe not.